# What calls a method inside an anonymous inner class?

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class

In the example program on
https://gist.github.com/bernii/5697073

In the code

```
this.wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
                System.out.println("Searching ...");
                return webDriver.findElement(By.id("resultStats")) != null;
            }
});
```

what calls the apply() method in the anonymous inner class?

Comment: This is always just me, but it is important to annotate @Override when overridding methods. Even though both you and I know you are overriding the `apply(WebDriver webDriver)` method, marking the annotation is important to show that you know you are overriding a method and that you know this is a method that will be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the `until` method, which receives the `ExpectedCondition<Boolean>` instance. That's the only method that can call it (unless the `until` method stores a reference to that instance in some instance variable (or static variable), and some other method uses that reference to call the `apply` method some other time).

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous inner class is like local classes except that they do not have a name.
Subclass of ExpectedCondition will be created in background which will call the method inside it.